# Can we catch multiple exception at a same time in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am a newbie to Visual Basic and trying to execute the below code of try and catch block. I am just checking that can we catch multiple exception in VB.net at same time. But i am just getting only one message. Kindly explain me clearly.

The code is here under

```
Public Class tempIsZeroException : Inherits System.Exception
    Public Sub New(ByVal mesage As String)
        MyBase.New(mesage)
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("ENter any number")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("ENter any number")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Try

            If a = 0 Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("asdf")
            End If
            If b = 0 Then
                Throw New tempIsZeroException("Exception caught")
            End If
        Catch ex As TempIsZeroException
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message())
        Catch ex1 As ApplicationException
            Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message())
        End Try
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: When you throw one of the exceptions the code jumps to the related catch block, performs whatever code is present in the catch block and then jumps outside the End Try. It is not clear what do you expect to happen from this code..

Answer (score 1):

You can catch multiple exceptions in a try block, but the exceptions do not get raised simultaneously (at least not in the code you have posted).

In other words, the first exception that is raised is the first exception that is caught.

So in your code, if `a = 0` then `ApplicationException` will be caught while if `b = 0` then `tempIsZeroException` will be caught, and if both `a` and `b` were to equal `0` then `ApplicationException` will be the exception raised since the `If a = 0` block will be hit first and the exception thrown and caught, bypassing the `If b = 0` block.

Hope that can add some clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much @txtechhelp